# Javascript Object: Basic Knowledge Gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

trying to create a set of of html form option/select fields that are driven by a google spreadsheet, to steer users to specific choices.  think a hat that is available in red, blue or black, a tshirt that is available in blue, green or red. the source data has the same value in col 1 for many rows, and unique values in col 2.  the colors are specific to each product. (the spreadsheet structure can not be changed.)

i'm trying to group the rows by product, so i can populate a product dropdown, then a colors dropdown that is keyed to that product. that's where i'm stuck.

i have the data loading ok and can do the form displays stuff, just need some insight into how to end how to structure an array like this:

```
var productsAndColors = [];
productsAndColors[0] = new Array("hat", ["pink", "red", "blue"]);
```

just quoting the iffy bit here:

```
for (i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
    product = entry.gsx$product.$t;
    productsAndColors[i] = ['', []];
    if (productCheck != product) {
        productsAndColors[i][0] = product;
        thisShape = product;
    }
    color = entry.gsx$color.$t;
    productsAndColors[i][1].push(color);
}
```

this creates an array per row, just can't seem to figure out a way to group the rows.  i realize this is cavemanish.

thanks for your thoughts.

http://jsfiddle.net/hartogsmith/SqNNk/

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkT3oKFSug31dGhva1lpWkhDOGxKaVJsNnpkZVpNbUE#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something that's a little less strictly-typed?

If you're comfortable with setting/reading `.value` as a string, from the first dropdown (ie: "product"), then you could have an object as simple as:

```
var products = {
    hat : {
        colours : [ "red", "green", "blue", "black", "grey" ]
    },
    shirt : {
        colours : [ "pink", "salmon", "mauve", "chartreuse" ]
    }
};
```

It could be more simple:

```
var products = {
    hat : [ "grey", "gray", "charcoal", "smoke" ],
    shirt : [/*...*/]
};
```

So why add "colour" as a property to each?
Simply because it's an adjective for an object that you might want to add more adjectives to: `.size : [], .shipping_options : [], .cut : []`.

```
shirt : {
    size : [],
    logo : [],
    cut  : []
}
```

And you really don't want to end up in a:

```
products[0][1][1]
products[1][2][3]
```

world.

Try this:

```
var Products = {},
    product_type,
    current_value,
    color_arr;

for (...) {
    product_type  = entry.gsx$product.$t;
    current_value = entry.gsx$color.$t;

    Products[product_type] = Products[product_type] || { colors : [] };
    /* same as:
        if (!Products.hat) { Products.hat = { colors : [] }; }
        ...basically, Products.hat == itself, else a new object
    */
    color_arr = Products[product_type].colors;
    color_arr.push(current_value);

}
```

Now, you can say `Products.hat.colors[1]`

And if you set your first dropdown up like this:

```
<select name="product">
    <option value="hat"  >Cap</option>
    <option value="shirt">Tee</option>
</select>
```

Then:

```
var type = product_select.value,
    avail_colours = Products[type].colors;
```

Comment: that's elegant and exactly what i was trying to do. thanks for helping w/ the problem and for helping further my understanding.